# How to evaluate front-end frameworks?

Tags: javascript, frontend, web-frameworks

I would like to understand how to conduct an independent evaluation of available popular JS front-end frameworks (React/Redux, Vue, Angular and others) for use in a new app we are trying to build ground up.

Many references online end up with conclusions and rates one framework over another. However, I find it difficult to relate with. Say, one report says learning curve for Vue is simpler than JSX for React. I don't find that argument very meaningful since it depends on one's exposure and idea of modularizing a UI component.

So, this SO question is raised to get receive a mixed bag of evaluation suggestions/strategies/schemes to conduct an independent inquiry into these available and popular frameworks.

What themes and approaches can I consider to evaluate popularly available front-end frameworks ?

Please advise.

Comment: as i always say: "There is something always better than what you are using" pick something that meets your needs. There is no guidelines, they differ from project to project.

Comment: Yes I agree. Could you give me an e.g. of meeting needs? I would like to hear some project variations and frameworks chosen to meet them. That is what I am looking to collect in this question.

Answer (score 1):

> This answer is given by jeremy-d and copy paste his answer because i
>   love react and i found react more interesting to work. It's be 1 year
>   in react and the react community is also very active.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/856942/jeremy-d

Advantages of using React:

- easy to know how a component is rendered, you just look at the render function.
- JSX makes it easy to read the code of your components. It is also really easy to see the layout, or how components are plugged/combined with each other.
- you can render React on the server-side.
- it is easy to test, and you can also integrate some tools like jest.
- it ensures readability and makes maintainability easier.
- you can use React with any framework (Backbone.js, Angular.js) as it is only a view layer.

What is not so good about React?

- it is only a view layer, you have still to plug your code for Ajax requests, events and so on. Some people get surprised by that.
- the library itself is pretty large.
- the learning curve can be steep.

If react-native is really how it was described, react is going to become even bigger.

Performance wise, it is really good as it relies on a virtual-dom to know what is really changing in your UI and will re-render only what has really changed.  It does have trouble with very large, slightly changing, lists of children (2000 `<li>` test), but can be optimized simply.

If you are not sure, just think about the big projects using React:
instagram, hipchat, facebook chat and so on.

Some resources:

- [React for the stupid people](http://blog.andrewray.me/reactjs-for-stupid-people/)
- [Rebuilding Hipchat with React](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/02/rebuilding-hipchat-with-react/)
- [Why React?](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/why-react.html)

And probably one of my favorite blog post [Why React is awesome?](http://jlongster.com/Removing-User-Interface-Complexity,-or-Why-React-is-Awesome)

Answer (score 1):

The community behind a framework is one of the most important factors for me. I want to be able to find answers on Stack Overflow for my questions, and I want to be able to find libraries and packages I can use that are actively maintained.

I like React most of all because it is easy to integrate into some other backend framework e.g. Rails.